# When i quote you from him you do not listen but when i quote you from Einstein you listen

Tags: word-choice, indirect-objects, prepositional-objects

Feeling great to join this network. I appreciate it. 
I have a question:  is it better to use the word *quote* or *cite* in such situation talking with a hypocrite person?

> "When I quote you from him you do not listen but when I quote you from
>   Einstein you listen."

or

> "When I cite you from him you do not listen but when I cite you from
>   Einstein you listen."

I want the more natural sounding, as English isn't my first language. I saw *cite* word is also used instead of *quote* word as synonym.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks for your question, but without more specifics about your concerns it sounds a bit like a proofreading request (which are off-topic here). Help us understand by including more details on your thinking and whatever research you've already done on the issue. "I'm worried that this doesn't sound right because…" or "These two sources [here] and [there] confuse me because it seems to me like they're saying…"

Comment: Dear Gossar  actually i wanted to know the usage of "quote" word.

Comment: In truth, I'm confused by the sentence as you've given it.  It's hard at first for me to tell who is being quoted and who is listening.

Comment: So something like "Is _quote_ the best verb to use here?  I considered using _read_ but didn't think it fit because…." maybe?  The more you tell us about your thought process, the better the question will be (and therefore less likely to be closed).

Comment: If this is a word-choice question about fluency or sounding natural, then it may get a more appropriate answer on ELL instead (since that sort of thing is the focus there).

Comment: Dear Gossar, thanks for you comment. Yeah i wanted to use quote as verb. But i actually i want to use this sentence. i will use "react" instead of "listen" word.

Comment: But i'm happy with the answer. The person who answered to this question she understood my question.

Comment: But since the idea of SE is to help everyone else who will ever have that same question, it's important that the question be well stated.

Comment: 1. I can't tell what you're asking.  It seems to either be grammar-related "how to use _quote_ with an indirect object" or word-choice "is _quote_ the best verb to use here".
2. There also isn't enough explanation of what you think the answers might be, where you've looked, or of what is confusing you.  The best questions often include something like "I thought it was… but it's not and I'm stuck.  I need help understanding… because of…. And here's what I've already found (or tried)…."

Comment: Are you asking **whether** to use _quote_ or **how** to use _quote_?

Comment: I want to use quote or cite just in this sentence.

Comment: If you're trying to decide between using _quote_ or _cite_ (which I'd say is **whether** to use _quote_) then a first step would be to provide examples of what you're trying to say using each verb. The current question already has _quote_ so how would you have written it using _cite_ instead?

Comment: i want natural sounding. As English isn't my first language.  cite word is also used instead of quote word as synonym i saw. I also told you earlier that guess i'm in such situation talking with Einstein fan or hypocrite. So i cant explain or elaborate anymore becauase i'm using this sentence may be rather i can use react word. I hope you're clear now dear Gossar.

Comment: [ask] has good advice on asking questions in a good way for SE.  If you aren't able to read the whole thing, at least try to think through these [four points:](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/is-this-a-good-justification-for-frequent-downvoting-and-closing/3013#3013) 
1. Let me explain why I'm asking this question.
2. Let me ask the question.
3. Let me tell you what I found when I tried to find the answer myself.
4. Let me explain why I'm still confused.
Failing to include *all four* of these things means either faulty assumptions, a _lot_ of back-and-forth, or both.

Comment: @Gossar We could migrate the question to ELL if the asker wishes it. Or the asker could simply delete here and ask at ELL.

Comment: Gossar thank for your reply. okay i will check out the points.  
 MetaEd please feel free to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Here's [another good resource](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for asking ELL questions in a way that gets you a good answer faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your intent, I would replace the pronoun with a more direct reference and drop *from*.

> When I quote you Joe Blow, you don't listen.  But when I quote you Einstein,
>   you listen.

You could instead say:

> When I quote from Joe Blow, you don't listen.  But when I quote from Einstein,
>   you listen.

but don't combine the two.  The use of an indirect object already implies a preposition.  Adding another just muddies the picture.

Comment: Gosser please guess i'm in such situation talking with a hypocrite person. I hope now it is clear to you. Thanks

Comment: This question seems more and more suited to [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) rather than ELU.  But it's still not yet a _good_ (complete) question.

Comment: Okay so what can i do? I'm new here, joined just today :(
Please edit me if possible or suggest me. I don't want to annoy community. Thanks.

Comment: Doubling up on implied prepositions causes confusion. "I throw John the ball" and "I throw to John" have very different meanings from "I throw John **to** the ball."

Answer (score 1):

A better way to phrase it is:

"When I quote him to you, you do not listen, but when I quote Einstein to you, you listen."

We don't say "I quote you" to mean "I quote someone when speaking to you". We say "I quote X" where X is the author of the words I quote.

"To", "at" or another preposition? I note that "quote shakespeare to you" has 41 Google hits, slightly more than "quote shakespeare at you" with 26. So I'd prefer "to".

Comment: Actually _quote_ can be used that way: "Let me quote you a price on that," "Quote him the riot act," or "I love a man who knows sonnets; quote me Shakespeare."  That's what made the question so confusing to me.

Comment: Gosser you mean i should use "cite" word instead of "quote" word??

Comment: @Gossar But each of your example usages of "quote" has two objects, rather than one object and one preposition phrase as in the OP's "I quote you from Einstein".

Comment: I have multiple problems with OP's sentence.  But my examples were in response to your saying,  "We don't say 'I quote you' to mean 'I quote someone when speaking to you'."  Often we do just that.  But you're right, what we _don't_ do is "quote IO **from** DO."